# Integral with limit of integration whose output is undefined

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

If I have the function f(x)=3 and I take the integral with respect to x from 0 to 2, the answer is 6. Now what if I have the function f(x)=3 BUT x is undefined at 0. Well, this means that a line has been subtracted from our original area of 6. But a line has zero area so we still have an area of 6 from 0 to 2 even if 0 is undefined. So why is it that f(x) must be continuous from 0 to 2 if we want to take the integral from 0 to 2.

Comment: To talk about the integrability of a function we only need to want that it be bounded, not continuous, in that interval.

Comment: So what you're saying is if I took the integral of $f(x)=3$ from $0$ to $2$ and $x=0.1, 0.3, 0.4,$ and $0.8$ were undefined I could still take the integral?

Comment: Yes. More surprising that a function like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function) can be integrated :)

Comment: I have taken the liberty to suppress tags "geometry" and "paradoxes" which are not meaningful here.

Comment: @Azif00 I have one last question. What is the definition of bounded in this case?

Comment: We say that $f$ is bounded in some interval $I$, if you can find $M>0$ such that $|f(x)|\leq M$ for all $x\in I$.

Comment: @Azif00 What if I had the piecewise function where $f(x)=4$ from $-2<x<-1$ and from $1<x<2$. $f$ is bounded on the interval from $-2$ to $2$ but I can't take the integral from $-2$ to $2$.

Comment: $f$ is not bounded in this case (it's not even defined in the entire interval, so you can't tell me that $|f(x)|\leq M$ for all $x$ that going from $-2$ to $2$). Also, for what purpose do this? If you do not believe me at all what I say you can investigate the rigorous definition of integral (both the Riemann and Darboux version).

Comment: @Azif00 Oh I see my mistake for some reason I thought only the x's where $f(x)$ is defined.

Comment: @Azif00 but you meant all the x's on the interval thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is right!

In principle we do not need to talk about the continuity of a function if we want to know whether or not it can be integrable in a certain closed interval. To talk about the integrability of a function we only need to want that it be bounded in that interval.

I leave you another, but similar, example. Take $f: [0,2] \to \Bbb R$ defined by
$$f(x) = \left\{ \begin{align}
1 & \textrm{ if } x=1 \\
0 & \textrm{ if } x\neq 1
\end{align} \right.$$
then
$$\int_0^2 f(x)dx=0$$
To prove this rigorously, we turn to the definition of integral. Suppose $P=\{ t_0,t_1,\dots,t_n\}$ is a partition of the interval $[0,2]$ (this means $t_0=0$, $t_n=2$ and $t_{i-1}<t_i$ for all $i=1,\dots,n$) with $t_{j-1}<1<t_j$ for some $j$ . Let's call 
$$m_i=\inf \, \{ f(x): t_{i-1}\leq x\leq t_i \}$$
$$M_i=\sup \, \{ f(x): t_{i-1}\leq x\leq t_i \}$$
for $i=1,2,\dots,n$. Then $m_i=M_i=0$ if $i\neq j$, but $m_j=0$ and $M_j=1$. Since the lower and upper sums turns into
$$L(f,P)=\sum_{i=1}^n m_i(t_i-t_{i-1})=0$$
$$U(f,P)=\sum_{i=1}^n M_i(t_i-t_{i-1})=t_j-t_{j-1}$$
it follows that, we can make the differences $U(f,P)-L(f,P)$ as small as possible (only choose a partition with $t_j-t_{j-1}$ enough small). This means that $f$ is integrable in that interval and since
$$L(f,Q)\leq 0\leq U(f,Q) \quad \textrm{for all the partitions } Q$$
it follows
$$\int_0^2 f(x)dx=0$$
as we want to show. (The latter is because the integral is defined as the infimum of all the upper sums and the supremum of all the lower sums.)